# Storing the time in Java

Tags: java, time

I am fresh new student in programming and I'd like to know how to store the time with PM or AM. For example the user may enter the next time : 10:45 PM

Then 10 will be stored in a variable `hh`, 45 in `mm` and `PM` in aa for example. Here is my code that I have try

```
String a = sc.next();

String [] b = a.split(":");
String [] c = a.split(" ");

int hh = Integer.parseInt(b[0]);
int mm = Integer.parseInt(b[1]);
String aa = c[1];

System.out.println(aa);
```

Comment: An important part of programming is using the right tool for a task. In your case a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) would be appropriate. You can then use its methods to query the hour/minute etc.

Comment: However if the input time given always as the same format your code is good but c will split in `c = {"10:45", "PM"}` you might want to split `b` instead.

Comment: Side note: give your variables more descriptive names. `a` becomes `input`, `hh` becomes `hours`, `mm` becomes `minutes`. `aa` is more tricky but might become `period`.

Comment: @Michael `amPm`?

Comment: How much validation do you need? `Integer.parseInt()` already verifies that 10 and 45 are numbers (though there is no range check). You might want to check that the string after the space is either AM or PM and not 47 or some other nonsense. You may also use an `enum` for the possible values AM and PM. All assuming you are required to code this by hand and not use `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` as one would in production code.

Comment: `LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(a, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH));` (not tested).

Comment: @assylias Hm. I don't like it. But it is less ambiguous, and it seems like it's [been used before](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/AmPm.html). I'm surprised there's no defined term which covers both (perhaps 'meridium' would be a good choice?)

Comment: @Michael FWIW in java.time the enum name is AMPM_OF_DAY.

Comment: @assylias Yeah, that's just terrible. Well, [*two hard things*](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)...

Answer (score 3):

As assylias said you should maybe take a look at [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). And using a homemade [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) in order to format your desired input String.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a");
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse("10:45 pm", formatter);
int hh = localTime.getHour(); 
// int hh = localTime.get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_AMPM); // To get 10 instead of 22 for example (see comments)
int mm = localTime.getMinute();
String aa = localTime.get(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY) == 0 ? "AM" : "PM";
// String aa = localTime.isBefore(LocalTime.NOON) ? "AM":"PM";
```

But however if you really want the user to input the time, always following the same format you can do do the following :

```
String a = sc.next();

String [] b = a.split(":");
String [] c = b.split(" ");

int hh = Integer.parseInt(b[0]);
int mm = Integer.parseInt(c[0]);
String aa = c[1];
```

Using your code.

Comment: You may also give the solution for using `LocalTime`, together with your current solution.

Comment: To get the PM is there a better way than checking if it's before noon ?